# CAML filter to get the current month from the list?

Tags: sharepoint, caml

In SharePoint 2010, I need to get items from a list based on a condition. Considering one of the fields to be 'Date' of type DateTime, the condition is:

Get Current Month Data.

How do I filter the list items based on this condition using CAML query?

By,
Raji

Answer (score 3):

Use [SPUtility.CreateISO8601DateTimeFromSystemDateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.sputility.createiso8601datetimefromsystemdatetime.aspx) to create relevant dateTime string

```
DateTime firstDay = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, 1);
Sting stringQuery =
String.Format(@"<And>
                  <Geq>
                   <FieldRef Name='Date' />
                   <Value Type='DateTime'>{0}</Value>
                 </Geq>
                 <Leq>
                  <FieldRef Name='Date' />
                  <Value Type='DateTime'>{1}</Value>
                 </Leq>
                </And>", 
                SPUtility.CreateISO8601DateTimeFromSystemDateTime(firstDay),
                SPUtility.CreateISO8601DateTimeFromSystemDateTime(firstDay .AddMonths(1)));
SPQuery query = new SPQuery(stringQuery);
```